# Extendable, multifunctional mediaplayer for linux (opensuse)

Tags: linux, opensuse

Can you please recommend me mediaplayer for linux with the following functions - turning computer off if playlist is finished and with ability to add outside audio track to video. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC seems to can od that:
Shutdown the system: http://www.instantfundas.com/2011/06/auto-shutdown-computer-after-vlc-media.html
And open file with parameters action allows you to play your sound path along the video.

Just dig it.